# What does 'I am feeling greatly humbled to think you are my future partner, darling' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

What does humbled mean in the following sentence?

> 'I am feeling greatly humbled to think you are my future partner, darling'

humbled means :cause (someone) to feel less important or proud.

So does the person who said that want to say that he or she is feeling less important because of her or his future partner ?

Am I wrong ?

Comment: Source please!  If you quote a line please tell us where you read or heard that line said or spoken.

Comment: see how this question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3019/what-is-the-meaning-of-i-am-humbled-by-xyz was asked

Comment: to feel humbled: when I see **how great or wonderful you are**, I realize that my own sense of greatness was too much. You are the superior person.

Comment: Lambie , that answer is great. Thank you.